# How to count how many posts the user has commented on?

Tags: php, wordpress, count

I know how to get the number of all comments written by a specific user, but how to count how many posts the user has commented on (in WordPress).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you want to count the comments a user made on posts:

You can use `get_comments()` function

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/

which accepts an array of arguments

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment_query/__construct/

In your arguments array, you use `user_id` to only get comments of this user. You also use `count` to return the number of comments.

The code looks like this:

```
<?php
    $comments_args = array(
        'user_id' => 12,   // Your user ID, for example user with id 12
        'count'   => true // Return count
    );
    $comments_count = get_comments( $comments_args );

    echo $comments_count;
?>
```

You now have the number of comments the user with id 12 wrote.

---

### If you want to count the posts where the user added one or more comments:

You can use `WP_Query` and run through your posts and use `wp_list_pluck()` to pluck the field out of each object.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' =>-1,
    'post__in' => array_unique( 
         wp_list_pluck( 
            get_comments( array(
                'user_id' => get_current_user_id() 
                )
            ),       
            'comment_post_ID' 
         )
    ),
);
$comment_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
$counter = 0;
if ( $comment_query ->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $comment_query ->have_posts() ) {
        $comment_query ->the_post();
            $counter++;
            // or display title or something
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

You can now display the number using `echo $counter;`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your code works, but that's not what I'm looking for. I don't want to get the number of comments posted by users. I need to get the **number of posts** where the user added at least one comment.

Comment: I added 2 comments to 1 post. Using your code, the returned number is 2 instead 1.

Comment: Aaah, ok I think I got it. Take a look at my edited answer. Sorry for not getting your question.